# Construction of an Unbounded Quotient of Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to construct a sequence $\left(\varepsilon_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\left(0,1/2\right)$ such that $\left(\varepsilon_n/\varepsilon_{n+1}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\notin\ell^\infty$, i.e.,

$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{\varepsilon_n}{\varepsilon_{n+1}}=\infty\tag*{?}$$

I ask because I saw in the hypothesis of a theorem the requirement that such a sequence $\left(\varepsilon_n/\varepsilon_{n+1}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be in $\ell^\infty$ (and wondered whether it is redundant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\varepsilon_1 = \dfrac14$ and $\varepsilon_{n+1} = \dfrac {\varepsilon_n} n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon_{2k}=\dfrac{1}{2^{2k}}$, $\epsilon_{2k+1}=\dfrac{1}{e^{2k+1}}$, then $\dfrac{\epsilon_{2k}}{\epsilon_{2k+1}}=\left(\dfrac{e}{2}\right)^{2k}\cdot e$, $k=1,2,...$, and $\sup_{n}\dfrac{\epsilon_{n}}{\epsilon_{n+1}}\geq\dfrac{\epsilon_{2k}}{\epsilon_{2k+1}}$.